System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint
I have created an Apex REST endpoint and I want to test it using an integration user that I've also just set up. The integration user is using the "Salesforce Integration" User License.
I've created two Permission Sets and added them to the user:

Perm Set License: Salesforce Integration (grants access to the Apex class where the REST endpoint is defined as well as assigns the Connected App)
Perm Set License: Salesforce API Integration (assigns the External Credential Principal Access and grants CRUD on UserExternalCredential)

I created a Connected App and External Credential and set the Connected App's Client Credentials "Run As" user to the integration user. The Connected App grants:

Access the identity URL service (id, profile, email, address, phone)
Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
Manage user data via APIs (api)

I don't have any scopes set on the External Credential.
Upon trying to make a callout to the Apex REST resource, I receive the following error:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setEndpoint('callout:my_named_credential/services/apexrest/my-endpoint-uri');

HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
System.debug(res.getBody());

System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "my_named_credential" might not exist.
I'm not sure what I've missed in terms of configuration. This configuration works when I make the request using my admin user, but I get that error when trying the integration user.
NOTE: I have found past suggestions to add some degree of access to UserExternalCredentials on the running user. However, this has not resolved the issue (tried all levels of access from Read to Modify All).

Just to confirm - you also added the Permission Set Feature License for the API user - that step always catches me out

@BritishBoyinDC Are you referring to the Salesforce API Integration "Permission Set License Assignment"? If so, yes, that's added to the Integration User.

According to the doc, sfap_api is "reserved for future use".  Is there a reason you don't want to use the plainapi scope?

@DavidCheng Apologies, that was a mistake and I had changed it before testing to api

When you say "Perm Set LIcense ... assigns the Connected App", do you mean that you've assigned the permission set (not license) to the connected app and set  "Admin approved users are pre-authorized"?

@DavidCheng The Connected App is added to the Perm Set which is assigned to the Integration User. The Connected App is configured with "All users may self-authorize."

is this using External Credentials in lieu of legacy Named Credentials. If so, the Permission Set needs to include External Credential Access to the External Credential

@cropredy No, I hadn't configured an External Credential. My only objective is to make a callout from anonymous apex to an Apex REST endpoint defined in this same org.

@cropredy I'm just now reading about External Credentials, which is new to me. I've set it up and assigned the principal to a perm set, which I've assigned to myself (as an admin user), but I'm getting "Unable to fetch the OAuth token." As an admin, I've got modify all data, but to be sure, I added Read access on UserExternalCredential.

@cropredy Okay, after further tinkering, I've got everything working using an External Credential with the Connected App having Client Credentials Flow enabled and the Integration User set as "Run As"...but only when I'm performing the callout using my admin user. When I try as the Integration (API Only) user, we're back to "System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint."

have you assigned the external credential principal access to the integration user's Perm set? and, of course, CRUD access on UserExternalCredential

@cropredy yes to both

contradictory information here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404355/fyi-apparently-salesforce-integration-user-license-doesnt-work-with-named-exte; latest answer is what I would expect.  You might need to [edit] OP with details of your Perm set, perm set assignment

@cropredy Sorry, I updated my post right after your my last comment because I realized it was out-of-date based on changes I've made. Based on that other post, am I to understand that this configuration isn't achievable with an Integration User license?

test it using an integration user : please edit your question and show how exactly you're doing this. The connected app is on the other (receiving) side of this call, it's irrelevant to your question.
